# Is it allowed/tolerated to ask the same question somewhere else?

Tags: discussion, asking-questions, etiquette, cross-posting

For example, I recently saw a question in which someone commented "The author also asked this question on r/haskell", with a link to a reddit post.

This seems to me disapproving, so I would like to inquire about the general consensus on such matters.

Comment: Yes, it's allowed and tolerated. Anything goes as long as the question is self-contained and otherwise follows SO rules.

Comment: Yes, I will add links to cross-posts outside of the network. The reason is netiquette that is now 20 or 30 years old - if there is no declaration of deliberate duplicates, then a reader may help on one of those threads without being able to check if it was solved elsewhere. This will broadly be a waste of their time. Thus, it is not the duplication that is a problem, it is failing to declare it.

Comment: I'm curious why you think this is a bad idea? As long as the content is owned by the OP, then why would there be an issue?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It is reasonably expected that people post details of any cross-posting outside Stack Overflow (more broadly, Stack Exchange). Reasons include

1. People who might answer should want to know if the question is already answered elsewhere -- not least to avoid wasting their time writing the same answer or an inferior answer.
2. People who are interested in an answer should want to know too, because presumably they don't much mind where a (good) answer is to be found.

Note that nothing stops individuals belonging to both groups, #1 and #2, as having an answer need not stop you being interested in other answers, unless the question is to you trivial.

It follows that it is reasonable -- indeed constructive -- to inform others on SE of cross-posting elsewhere if the OP fails to do this.

Nothing in this is necessarily questioning anyone's motives, although there is a spectrum of behaviour. Sometimes one sees postings of the same question in every possible place (e.g. with an excuse that the OP is desperate or their need is urgent). Sometimes there is a naive assumption that people who follow one site don't look at any other site, so won't notice duplicates on other sites. Conversely, it is because people don't look everywhere that notice of cross-posting is helpful.

I've seen comments that asking the same question in two or more places is offensive to people in any one place, as you're doubting that (in this case) people on SE can be trusted to provide a good answer fast enough -- or you're implying that you don't care that people might unwittingly duplicate effort. Sometimes this goes along with an idea that SE is a helpline, so that people are somehow obliged to answer your question because you have one.

I don't go along with all of that, but I note that these opinions exist.

In short, telling people that you cross-posted the same question is polite and never redundant. And telling people that the same question was posted elsewhere by the OP is helpful whenever that happens and the OP doesn't explain.

Any disapproval can be thought of as personal and private -- unless perhaps the OP repeatedly and visibly does this. At the same time what the OP does outside SE could well be considered beyond the concern of SE.

Answer (score 14):

As long as the user **is not cross-posting on sites on the Stack Exchange network**, doing additional research elsewhere is not only allowed, but a good idea. The more research, the better.

If the user find the answer to their question by asking elsewhere, they can always post a an answer to their question here so it helps future visitors with the same issue.

As long as the question quality is up to scratch and follows the site's topicality rules, it's fair game.

Comment: If the question is indeed `up to scratch and follows the site's topicality rules`, what is the problem with cross-posting? I would have thought that the real problem with something like that would be that something on-topic on one SE site is likely not on topic on almost all other sites, but it something *happens* to be on-topic on multiple sites, what would be the issue with cross-posting (if the post on one site hasn't gotten an answer)?

Comment: Snow, see [this](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/64068/is-cross-posting-a-question-on-multiple-stack-exchange-sites-permitted-if-the-qu).

Comment: Whenever I've seen this happen, which is often, it doesn't count as "additional research elsewhere". It is just asking the same question elsewhere. But I suffer from an academic's definition of research, which is doing original work to find out something new, not just trying to find out what is already known by somebody.

Answer (score 0):

There are circumstances in which cross-posting of the sort you describe is understandably frowned upon (for instance, when the OP posts homework questions verbatim to multiple venues whose readerships have significant overlap). However, as far as Stack Overflow is concerned it is preferable to avoid discussion of the motives of the OP, and evaluate questions on their own merits. That being so, there is little point in raising that issue in a comment thread here.